# The import javax.sound cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

I have a problem http://prntscr.com/437w8p

I have java jre8 installed
I tried with version jre7 and same.

Can someone please help me? I've tried everything...

Comment: android does not suppirt java 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) does not have `javax.sound`. You need to use [Android media APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) for audio playback on Android.

Comment: But I want to read samples from .wav, so I thought to use AudioInputStream. Is there some other way? Thanks!

Comment: @fraxmanutd: I have not researched how to read samples from `.wav` files, but I know that `AudioInputStream` is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: @fraxmanutd: Either find a WAV parsing library that only uses APIs available on Android, or write one yourself. The latter option [is not that difficult](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).